# Using the Group By Function in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

I have to find the number of products sold by Boris Davidovich (SalesmanId "6").  But I have to use the name in the query, and not the ID, and I would like to use GROUP BY.

So far this is what I have written:

```
SELECT Salesmen.FirstName, Salesmen.LastName,  COUNT(ProductsSales.QuantitySold)
FROM ProductsSales LEFT JOIN Salesmen
ON Salesmen.FirstName = Boris AND Salesmen.LastName = Davidovich
```

I'm stuck from where I go from here.

Here is the data that I have to work with.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `sellerid` is the `salesmanid`, then you need to change your `join` to match on those fields.  The you can use `group by` accordingly, but with `sum` instead of `count`:

```
SELECT s.SellerId, s.FirstName, s.LastName, SUM(ps.QuantitySold) 
FROM Salesmen S JOIN 
    ProductsSales PS ON S.sellerid = PS.salesmanid 
WHERE S.FirstName = 'Boris' AND S.LastName = 'Davidovich'
GROUP BY s.SellerId, s.FirstName, s.LastName
```

Also, there's no need for an `outer join` unless you want to return sales people without any sales.  If that's the case, you'll want to change the `inner join` to a `left join` and use `coalesce` to get 0 instead of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL Select statement could be modified as shown below:

```
    SELECT First(Salesmen.FirstName) As FN, Fist(Salesmen.LastName) As LN, SUM (ProductsSales.QuantitySold) As TotalProd 
    FROM Salesmen  INNER JOIN ProductsSales  ON Salesmen.SalesmanId = ProductsSales.SellerId 
    WHERE (Salesmen.FirstName= 'Boris' AND Salesmen.LastName = 'Davidovich')
GROUP BY Salesmen.SalesmanID
```

Comment: Aggregation without `group by` won't work (unless this is `mysql` and then will only return a random result).  Also, it looks like the OP wants to `sum` the records versus `count` them.  So not sure this will work...

Comment: That's right, it should be SUM(). It also works in MS Access without GROUP BY. Best regards,